# access a string from an xml file that is deeper in the package? android

Tags: android

i have some strings in string.xml that i would like to access from the same package. im able to grab them from com.package.activity but i am not able to get them from com.package.domain.modern.

i tried something like this from com.package.domain.modern:

```
String temp = "" + (com.package.activity.R.string.string);
```

and this an int returns "2131361874".

but when i try to use `(R.string.name_of_string)` in com.package. activity, it works fine.
`getResources().getString(R.string.name_of_string)` also works from there.

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you are accessing the `string`, pass a reference of the `context` and then try

```
mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.name_of_string);
```

It will return the actual string.

Comment: how do i "pass a ref of the context"? sorry, i am a newbie

Comment: the class you are using have a constructor? Where it initialized?